# Node reference: Select an exisiting node, or create a new one

Tags: entities, nodes

I am using Drupal 7, with the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module installed.

I was wondering if there is a way (or perhaps another module) so I can select an existing node from the list or create a new one on the fly (ajax or non ajax)?

So for example I have a button for create new node and automatically select the new node as a reference?

I'd like to have the node reference as a LIST only, not auto complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Node Reference Create Module](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate).

Comment: Thank you but that modules doesn't work on drop down menues

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is an existing module recipe that does everything you describe. You could combine the standard node reference list selector with the [Node Reference URL Widget module](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) to meet your requirements.  NodeReference_url expects the referencing nid as a parameter in the URL, so you could add a hyperlink through a module or theme template to render anywhere (next to the standard list or add an extra choice "Add New" to the list with a JQuery onChange).  Node Reference URL lets you set a return page to the "Previous page" when editing the node reference field admin/structure/types/manage/[your content type]/fields/field_[your field] for a smooth round trip.

I realize this is not an AJAX solution, but these pieces could be converted to such in a custom module and might get you started.

Out of the box, Node Reference Create is as close as you can get I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [References dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) also. The module extends reference fields like the user, entity and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog.